# "Can you do this" or "Can you please do this" or "Could you please do this"?

Tags: politeness

Which is the correct response to someone if they want you to do this?

Comment: What is your question? What to answer, or which question of the three is correct?

Answer (score 2):

'**Could you please do this**' is most appropriate if you're politely asking someone to do something.

**Can you do this...** can also mean like you're asking if they can do the job or not. You can change it to '**Can you do this for me**,' to clear the confusion.

**Can you please do this**... is okay, too, because the word 'please' automatically tells us that you're requesting someone to do something.